# Confidence interval on part of normal distribution

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Given an sample of data set $X$ which is normal-distributed to $\mathscr N(\mu=240,\sigma)$, I want to find the 95% confidence interval of $\max(\mu-200,0)$. As the $\max(\mu-200,0)$ cut the normal-distribution curve at the point of $200$, the sample of $\max(\mu-200,0)$ is not more normal distributed. Therefore what is a reasonable $95\%$ confidence interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distribution contains a $\delta$-function at $x=0$ of probability mass equal to the probability mass of your normal distribution less than the value $x=200$.  (This will involve an error function.)  The remaining probability mass will be due to the portion of your Gaussian to the right of $x = 200$.  As such, your $95\%$ confidence interval will extend from $x=0$ up to the value $x$ for which $5\%$ of the total probability mass (or $10\%$ of the truncated Gaussian) is above $x$.  Clearly, this is expressed as an error function.

Comment: But my max function is defined as $max[\mu-200,0]$ with $\mu=240$. How comes that $\delta$ function has prob mass of 0.5?

Comment: Oh... I misread your question, thinking that you requested $\max (\mu - 240, 0)$ rather than $\max (\mu - 200, 0)$.  Let me re-do the solution.

Comment: Thanks! I can't really follow the point with 5% of the total probability mass above x=0. Is this not just equivalent to the 5% of the truncated Gaussian? Do I need to choose the 90% percentile of the truncated gaussian to represent my 95% confidence interval?

Comment: You want the value $x$ for which just $5\%$ of the *total* probability mass is above $x$.  So find the point $x$ for which $5\%$ of the given normal distribution is above $x$, and then merely translate that (subtract off) 200.  Sketch the distributions to see all this.

Comment: As my x follow a normal distribution, my statistical error is also symmetric. Hence I would choose 97.5% percentile and 2.5% percentile to calculate my 95%. But now my x is not more symmetric, I dont know if it is right, just to consider the one side percentile, namely the 95% of my truncated gaussian distribution.

Comment: The $95\%$ confidence interval is the range of values of $x$ for which $95\%$ of the probability mass exists.  Given the "spike" at $x=0$, this range will certainly include the value $x=0$.  (Think about it...)

Comment: Sorry I miss understood you. The confidence interval is not unique and must contain x=0, this is clear. I am asking from a practical view, what is more a reasonable choice of such a realisation. I mean suppose $P(x=0)=0.4$. From the rest of 0.6, I can choose any interval with u>0, such that P(u<x<v)=0.55 for a 95% confidence interval. My question is rather how to choose such a [u,v] to represent my error in my estimates for $max(\mu-200,0)$ .(I mean i can choose u=0 then it would be my 95 percentile of x, or I can choose both side such that u<0.)

Comment: One often chooses the symmetric confidence interval centered on the mean, but in highly skewed distributions this might not be appropriate.